# SELECT DISTINCT where records greater than 1

Tags: php, sql

I have the following `sql`:

`SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM myTable WHERE foo IS NOT NULL ORDER BY foo ASC`

This works fine, retrieveing all the distinct fields within this column. The issue I have is that I would like to only select the `DISTINCT` fields which have more than 1 record within the database. Is this possible without doing it with php/loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT foo FROM myTable 
WHERE foo IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY foo 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY foo ASC
```